# How to drag and drop nodes from TVirtualStringTree into a VCL control with DragType dtOLE?

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview, tvirtualstringtree

Is it possible to drag and drop nodes from `TVirtualStringTree` into a VCL control when the `DragType` is set to `dtOLE` (not `dtVCL`)

I have a situation where I need to be able to drag nodes from one VT to another VT (`dtOLE` works fine), but at the same time, while dragging, I need an option to be able to drop the nodes into a `TListBox` (or other VCL control).

I tried setting `DragAcceptFiles()` API for the `TListBox` handle, but it had no effect.

How can it be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `DragAcceptFiles` property on `TListBox`.  If you mean that you are calling the Win32 API [`DragAcceptFiles()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776406.aspx) function on the `TListBox.Handle` window, that would only work if:

1. you manually subclass the `TListBox.WindowProc` property to handle the [`WM_DROPFILES`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774303.aspx) window message.
2. `TVirtualStringTree` provides the [`CF_HDROP`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776902.aspx#CF_HDROP) format during OLE dragging.

2 is not true, though.  `CF_HDROP` is meant only for dragging filesystem paths, which is not what `TVirtualStringTree` drags.  So using `DragAcceptFiles()` is out.

`TVirtualStringTree` (and other `TBaseVirtualTree` descendants) uses custom data formats during OLE dragging (the interface section of the `VirtualTrees.pas` unit declares these format IDs, so you do not need to register them manually in your own code):

- `CF_VIRTUALTREE` contains an `IStream` or `HGLOBAL` holding a serialized form of the selected tree nodes that are being dragged.  The serialization is comprised of a series of data chunks describing each node.  You will have to refer to the implementation of the `VirtualTree.pas` unit to decipher this format (I'm not going to do it here).
- `CF_VTREFERENCE` contains an `HGLOBAL` holding a `TVTReference` record (which is also declared in the interface section of the `VirtualTrees.pas` unit) containing a pointer to the actual `TBaseVirtualTree` object that is being dragged from and the ID of the process that the tree belongs to.

So, in order for you to be able to drop tree nodes onto the `TListBox`, you will have to do the following:

1. write a class that implements the [`IDropTarget`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679679.aspx) interface (or use a pre-existing implementation, such as from [Anders Melander's Drag&Drop suite](http://melander.dk/delphi/dragdrop)).
2. register that class with the `TListBox.Handle` window using [`RegisterDragDrop()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678405.aspx).
3. in your `IDropTarget` implementation, you can query the provided `IDataObject` for the `CF_VIRTUALTREE` and `CF_VTREFERENCE` formats.  If successful, your `Drop()` method will have access to the tree node data that is being dragged and can copy it into the `TListBox` as needed.

Assuming your `TListBox` exists in the same process as the `TVirtualStringTree` being dragged from, I would suggest focusing on just `CF_VTREFERENCE`, since it is a very small and simple format (see the implementation of the `TBaseVirtualTree.GetTreeFromDataObject()` method), and parsing the `CF_VIRTUALTREE` data would be overkill (see the implementation of the `TBaseVirtualTree.ProcessOLEData()` method) when you can just enumerate through the source `TVirtualStringTree` directly instead.

Comment: I was referring to DragAcceptFiles() API. I realized later it was nonsense. In any case your answer helped me big time. thanks! I did used `CF_VTREFERENCE`, and got the nodes selection using `VT.GetSortedSelection`